# Error to import PyInstaller Module and compile it

Tags: python, import, pyinstaller

I am trying to import the PyInstaller module in `myscript.py`, It work well as py extension but it doesn't work when I compile it with PyInstaller.

```
from PyInstaller.__main__ import run
```

And I have this message when I execute `myscript.exe` :

```
PyInstaller cannot check for assembly depencies. Please install PyWin32 or pywin32-ctypes.

pip install pypiwin32
```

I looked and I have already this module "pypiwin32". I searched everywhere before to post my request here. Any help is welcome, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the python  you are installing to. The best way is to cmd to the pip python dir and run install from there.

Other option is to use Anaconda. It will install to the right one.

If you have few pythons on your computer the "pip install" will choose the first one he see's in PATH.

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure because I have only python 3.7.2 installed on my computer. I tried to install the pypiwin32 but it is already present version 224.